# spring data elastic search Not a valid protocol version: This is not an HTTP port

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, testcontainers

I have the following elastic-search container configuration in my test case

```
    @Container
    public static  GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer<>("elasticsearch:7.7.0")
        .withExposedPorts(9200,9300).withEnv("discovery.type","single-node")
        .withNetwork(Network.newNetwork())
        .withNetworkAliases("someNetwork");
```

In a @BeforeAll annotated method I elasticsearch url property like this

```
System.setProperty("spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes", container.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + container.getMappedPort(9300));
```

From power shell when I check the running containers (during the test case debug pause), I find something like this under ports column : **0.0.0.0:32844->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32843->9300/tcp**
When I print **container.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + container.getMappedPort(9300)**, I get the same port mapped to 9300 in the container ports column, in this case **localhost:32843**, for sure the port is random and get changed in every new run.

when the code **`conf = repo.save(conf);** run, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: **Not a valid protocol version: This is not an HTTP port**
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:209)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:245)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.ParseException: Not a valid protocol version: This is not an HTTP port
>       at org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseProtocolVersion(BasicLineParser.java:148)
>       at org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseStatusLine(BasicLineParser.java:366)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpResponseParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:112)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpResponseParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:50)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeadLine(AbstractMessageParser.java:156)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:207)
>       ... 11 more

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a REST client to access Elasticsearch on port 9300. This is the port for the TransportClient. Wit a REST client you need to target port 9200.

Comment: I get a timeout exception:org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-1 [ACTIVE]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-1 [ACTIVE]

Comment: Thnx..I have increased both socketTimeout and connectTimeout to 10 seconds...It's a silly not realistic value, but it's OK for my windows dev machine.

Comment: I'm creating highLevelRestClient using both the ports and sometimes RestClient works and sometimes it fails with the same error. I think I should not use 9300. 

`RestHighLevelClient highLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost[] {
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200), new HttpHost("localhost", 9300) }));`

Comment: @VishalPatel 9200 is for http REST and 9300 for the native transport protocol. If you configure both for the restclient, it will choose one of both and fail when it gets the 9300